# Draw custom route on map

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-roads-api

I have university area and its Google map routing is undefined inside university.  I want to define the roads from academic building to parking because inside university the route on the map not shown.Now anyone guide me that how to define my  custom route on map. Application will be on android platform. Is Any service available regarding this problem. All suggestions will be appreciable.

Comment: That answer not addressing my problem because I am able to draw polyline form starting point to end point but I want show poly line line to my defined route or coordinates leading to this parking area, or you can share any other approach

Answer (score -1):

Check this once:
https://www.maps.ie/map-my-route/

I have not tried, but looks like you can define your route and use the route id in your app.

Comment: Good example but I want to show in android native app and update route with user location